# What is the Big O efficiency of this code?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, big-o

The question I was given requires me to get an output within 3 secs

The constraint given is 2<= len(a) <= 5000000 and 1 <= a[i] <= 10**9

Below is the code I have written.  I belive that the Big O efficiency of this code is linear or O(n) as I am only using one for loop. Is that the case? If can it run the max input size within 3 secs?

```
line = input()
m = line.split()
m.sort()
smallest_diff = 10 ** 9
for i in range(len(m)-1):
    diff = abs(int(m[i]) - int(m[i+1]))
    if diff < smallest_diff:
        smallest_diff = diff
    else:
        smallest_diff = smallest_diff
    if i+1 > len(m):
        break
print(smallest_diff)
```

Comment: Time complexity seems to be O(n) indeed, however, it has nothing to do with absolute time like 3 seconds or 5 seconds or however many seconds, it's a relative measure that allows you to compare it with other algorithms

Comment: @Matiiss i see but usually for a data set of this size would the code be able to complete it within the time limit?

Comment: that depends on a lot of factors

Comment: What is the point of `smallest_diff = smallest_diff`? In any event -- that `sort` gets you to `O(nlog(n))`

Comment: It's not the loop what matters here, but the `m.sort()`. That makes it O(n*log n), typically.

Comment: If you were to use radix sort, which you can on your positive integer elements below 1bn, then the complexity would be O(n) but it might be slower at sorting fewer elements. The Big O complexity only refers to asymptotic behaviour. You're sorting potentially millions of elements, so the performance of the sorting algorithm and the hardware you're running it on will matter. Try benchmarking some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your runtime complexity is currently O(N log(N)), dominated by the sort call. You're correct that the main work loop takes only O(N) time. However, the input size of 5*10^6 will be close to the borderline for what Python can get done in 3 seconds; you

I actually suspect your input loading may be eating up a lot of time. That's not an asymptotics issue; input is just often pretty slow. Here are things I'd try:

1. Check whether the website you're submitting to allows you to use PyPy instead of regular Python. You could still submit the same code either way, but it'll probably run a lot faster in PyPy.
2. Replace your first 2 lines with `m = map(int, input().split())`. This stores a list of `int` instead of `string`. `int`s make your code less memory-intensive and ints are what you want to use anyway. There are some more advanced tricks you could try to make the input loading steps even faster, like using [BytesIO](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63102), but I'm just mentioning for fun; you probably don't want to get into that right now.
3. You currently have a few other unnecessary lines of code that slow your program down slightly, but they won't affect the runtime much.

Bonus note: I don't know the exact problem you're trying to solve, but your code probably has a bug where you sort the data. Your `m` is a list of *strings*, not ints, so for example your code would consider this array to be already sorted: `['10', '3']` (because the string `'10'` comes before the string `'3'`). This bug would be fixed as a side effect of my suggestion (2) above, since if you store the data as ints then you'd instead get `[3, 10]` which I'm pretty sure is what you're intending.